# javascript mysql insert multiple values

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am trying to insert the request.body I receive which is struct the following into database

```
request.body = [{
        "createdAt": "2019-03-11T08:03:11.438",
        "deviceType": "type1",
        "deviceSerial": "123",
        "metricName": "metric1",
        "metricValue": "29"
    },
    {
        "createdAt": "2019-03-11T08:03:11.442",
        "deviceType": "type2",
        "deviceSerial": "234",
        "metricName": "metric2",
        "metricValue": "29"
    },
    {
        "createdAt": "2019-03-11T08:03:11.442",
        "deviceType": "type3",
        "deviceSerial": "345",
        "metricName": "metric3",
        "metricValue": "165"
    }
]
```

Trying to set the request.body into database:

```
var mysql = require('node-mysql');
var conn = mysql.createConnection({
    ...
});

var sql = "INSERT INTO Test (created_at, device_type, devices_serial, metric_name, metric_value) VALUES ?";

var values = request.body // <- Here it the problem, I guess

conn.query(sql, [values], function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    conn.end();
});
```

I am trying to understand how to construct the `var values` so it will fit to the following format:

```
var values = [
    ['2019-03-11T08:03:11.438', 'type1', '123', 'metric1', '29'],
    ['2019-03-11T08:03:11.438', 'type2', '234', 'metric2', '29'],
    ['2019-03-11T08:03:11.438', 'type3', '345', 'metric3', '165'],
];
```

Comment: What's the problem? Do you get any error? Is `request` defined at this point?

Comment: This solution works but probably not the best. generate sql like this 'Insert into...... values (?,?,?...?), (?,?,?...?)...' . Each () contains a record in database. And then spread params sequently.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** : Try this

```
    var mysql = require('node-mysql');
    var conn = mysql.createConnection({
        ...
    });

    var sql = "INSERT INTO Test (created_at, device_type, devices_serial, metric_name, metric_value) VALUES ?";

    var values = request.body.map(Object.values);

    conn.query(sql, [values], function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        conn.end();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the object values as Array

```
var values = request.body.map(r=>  Object.values(r));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var conn = mysql.createConnection({
    ..
});

let request = {};
request.body = [{
    "createdAt": "2019-03-11T08:03:11.438",
    "deviceType": "type1",
    "deviceSerial": "123",
    "metricName": "metric1",
    "metricValue": "29"
  },
  {
    "createdAt": "2019-03-11T08:03:11.442",
    "deviceType": "type2",
    "deviceSerial": "234",
    "metricName": "metric2",
    "metricValue": "29"
  },
  {
    "createdAt": "2019-03-11T08:03:11.442",
    "deviceType": "type3",
    "deviceSerial": "345",
    "metricName": "metric3",
    "metricValue": "165"
  }
];

// Convert to array of arrays. 
const values = request.body.map((obj) => Object.values(obj));

const sql = "INSERT INTO Test (created_at, device_type, devices_serial, metric_name, metric_value) VALUES ?";

conn.query(sql, [values], function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    conn.end();
});
```